# ORMLite change allowGeneratedIdInsert in onUpgrade

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite in my app.
I had to enable the `allowGeneratedIdInsert` flag for one of my fields (rows) of a class (table). I did this through annotations.

Now i also need to do this for users which will update the app. This means I need to increment the database version and do the same in my `onUpgrade` method.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Or do I have to copy my data, drop the table and then recreate it using `TableUtils`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not help with this field conversion.  You certainly can use the raw-update methods to alter your schema in the `onUpdate(...)` method:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-update

For information about upgrading your schema, see the docs:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/upgrade-schema